# How to read a word from std::istringstream without assigning to a tmp variable through >>?

Tags: c++, istringstream

I have a `std::string line` which contains a line of text read from a file. I then create a `istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream str(line);
```

to read this line. To get the first word, I do this:

```
std::string word;
str >> word;
```

Is there a way to get the word directly from `str`, without declaring the intermediate variable `word`?

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
if (str.get_next_word_directly() == "yes")
     do_something();
```

Comment: What do you mean _get directly_? Where should the value go?

Comment: Intermediate to what?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a named variable to do this;  it is possible to extract into a temporary but then you have no way of identifying that temporary to call `operator==` on it.

One option would be to wrap the extraction in a function, e.g.

```
std::string get_word(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string word;
    is >> word;
    return word;
}
```

and then you can write

```
if( get_word(str) == "yes" )
```

NB. There is a proposal for C++17 that would allow `str.get_word()` instead of `get_word(str)`; but for now you're stuck with `get_word(str)`.

Comment: Last I've heard, unified call syntax won't make it into C++17.